# FPDF Error wont allow google chart api, since no image extension

Tags: google-visualization, fpdf, html2pdf

```
FPDF error: Image file has no extension and no type was specified:
```

Is the error I receive when I try to have this:

```
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=LG-80294959&choe=UTF-8">
```

In my html, that FPDF will html2pdf convert.

So how can i do this? I really need this QR chart inside this pdf.

Comment: I also tried to put .jpg extension at the end. The chart still loads fine on browser but I receive the same error when through fpdf, what can i do??

Comment: Researched some more. Says i can do &.png, but does not work, same error.

Comment: So when using `https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=LG-80294959&choe=UTF-8&.png`, you get the exact same error? Looking through the source of FPDF and html2pdf, that should have worked. If it didn't, can you find the value of `FPDF::Image's` `$file` parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After spending hours on this exact problem I finally figured it out.  First, as others has suggested, I did NOT need to add a &.png at the end of my url.  The key turned out to be the spaces in the labels.

```
$chart_url = str_replace(" ","%20",$chart_url);

echo '< img src="'.$chart_url.'"/>'; (remove the space between < img)
```

The above worked perfectly.

Here is the full code as requested.  I removed the header and footer...

```
<?
import('html2pdf.class');           
ob_start();
?>
<style type="text/css">

</style>
<page backtop="120px" backbottom="105px" backleft="10mm" backright="10mm" style="font-size: 10pt">
<bookmark title="Test" level="0" ></bookmark>
<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=VS-26258807&choe=UTF-8" /> 
</page>
<?
$html = ob_get_clean();     
// init HTML2PDF
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'fr', true, 'UTF-8', array(0, 0, 0, 0));
// display the full page
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
// convert
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
// send the PDF
return $html2pdf->Output('shop_preview.pdf','true');
return $file;
```

Then I simply echo'd the returned '$file'.

Here is the fpdf class I use:  http://html2pdf.fr/en/download

Comment: Thanks for the efford. But still not working and same error. Try with this chart url and you will see: https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=VS-26258807&choe=UTF-8

Comment: I think you are having a different issue - I am not having a problem creating a pdf with your url - see this example: http://isecretshop.com/test/

Comment: Thanks for example. Can you post your full code for the creation of this pdf?

Comment: Can i get the html2pdf.class ? I found out that you may have a newer version of this class than me. Just make a http://pastebin.com of it and pass me the link. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry been offline today.  Here is a link to the package I use.  I switched to this one about 6 months ago.  It is significantly better: http://html2pdf.fr/en/download